# Assign factor values and make calculations by using Corine raster dataset as basis in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, ndvi, rusle

I am using ArcMap.

I have the Corine raster map which is consolidated by the the class codes (example 121) and some additional information.

The purpose is to calculate the Crop/Management factor for importing it in the RUSLE model.

What I would like to do to achieve this calculation is to:

- Assign manually the values of the factor (according to literature) when the code belongs to the arable classes (which can be done easily by adding a field in the attribute table and then edit it according to the code) &
- (The difficult part) Calculate the factor for the non-arable classes (code from 221-334) by using NDVI.

In particular the formula is `C = minC + range(C)* (1-NDVI)`

However, each class/code has a different min, range and NDVI value so I cannot just use the raster calculator.
I need to select somehow the value of each code and according to the respecting min and range values to calculate the formula by using the NDVI that corresponds to each pixel.

Comment: @PolyGeo I managed to find a way to do it. I used the reclassify tool to split the arable from the non-arable classes. Then I added the necessary fields (min, range) and I use the Lookup("rastername", "fieldname") function inside the Raster Calculator tool to do the necessary calculations with the NDVI. I am using ArcMap by the way. 

Thanks for asking.

Comment: I think you should self-answer your question using the area reserved for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do it. I used the reclassify tool to split the arable from the non-arable classes. Then I added the necessary fields (min, range) and I use the Lookup("rastername", "fieldname") function inside the Raster Calculator tool to do the necessary calculations with the NDVI.